# How to rewrite this PHP function to ruby?

Tags: php, ruby, function, preg-match

I am newbie in ruby and regular expressions and I have this function write in PHP, and I would need to rewrite it to Ruby.

```
function date_number_id($id_number) { 
    if (preg_match('~^([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{3,4})$~', $id_number, $match)) { 
        return (strlen($match[4]) < 4 || $match[1] >= 54 ? "19" : "20") . "$match[1]-" . sprintf("%02d", $match[2] % 50) . "-$match[3]"; 
    } 
    else
    {
      return false; 
    }
}
```

Could you help me please, with it?

Many thanks!

**EDIT:** This is a function that prints from the identification number the birthday day. The input is for example: `890807/5089`

Comment: It always helps to provide some input/output for people who are not into PHP but still willing to help.

Comment: Hm - that example won't match - you're requiring a slash after the first 6 chars in your regexp...

Comment: Sorry @Amadan, my inattention. Fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I missed something...

```
def date_number_id(id_number)
  match = /^([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{3,4})$/.match(id_number)
  if match
    return "#{match[4].to_i < 4 || match[1].to_i >= 54 ? '19' : '20'}#{match[1]}-#{sprintf("%02d", match[2].to_i % 50)}-#{match[3]}"
  else
    return false
  end
end
```

I think the mapping to PHP is obvious, but if there's something you don't understand why it is so, ask.